# FosRest 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I am using Symfony 2 and FOSRestBundle. And when i put this commande :

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X DELETE -d '{"test":{"field":"xxx"}}' http://localhost/tutonew/web/app_dev.php/api/test/4/delete
```

I Have this Error : **HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed**

I'm going to see my source code :

**1- First I set my config file :**

```
#app/config/config.yml sensio_framework_extra: view: annotations: false

fos_rest:

param_fetcher_listener: true
body_listener: true
format_listener: true
view:
    view_response_listener: 'force'
```

**2- Under my AdsAPIBundle I just insert the function :**

```
/**
 * @Rest\View(statusCode=204)
 * @Rest\Delete("/api/test/{id}/delete")
 * 
 */
public function deleteTestAction(Request $id) {

    $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->
            getManager()->
            getRepository("MinnAdsAPIBundle:Test");
    $entity = $repo->find($id);
    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find test entity!');
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->remove($entity);
    $em->flush();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i solved the problem. I just fix this

```
public function deleteTestAction(Request $id)
```

To this :

```
public function deleteTestAction($id)
```

And finally i launch this commande

```
curl -i -X DELETE -d '{"test":{"field":"xxx"}}' http://localhost/tutonew/web/app_dev.php/api/test/4/delete
```

And i will have this Code :

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
```